# HTML5 video loop src change on end play function not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a number of videos playing one by one in the same HTML5 video player

**HTML**

```
<video id="homevideo" width="100%" autoplay autobuffer>
    <source src="app/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

**JS**

```
video_count = 1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");
videoPlayer.addEventListener("ended", function (){
    video_count++;
    if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
    var nextVideo = "app/video" + video_count + ".mp4";
    videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
    videoPlayer.play();
}, false);
```

If I put an alert before playing, it's working. But without the alert it's not. Initialize the second video play:

```
videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
alert("a");
videoPlayer.play();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The html5 video element has an own eventtype onended, you dont need your own eventlistener.

Html:

```
<video id="homevideo" width="100%" autoplay onended="run()">
    <source src="app/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

and

Script:

```
video_count =1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");

function run(){
        video_count++;
        if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
        var nextVideo = "app/video"+video_count+".mp4";
        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
        videoPlayer.play();
   };
```

PS: Keep in mind that providing only one format for your video is not enough since no single format is supported by all major browsers yet.

EDIT:

[LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

Source: w3schools

At Media Events
Events triggered by medias like videos, images and audio (applies to all HTML elements, but is most common in media elements, like `<audio>`, `<embed>`, `<img>`, `<object>`, and `<video>`):

onended:
Script to be run when the media has reach the end (a useful event for messages like "thanks for listening")

Comment: Is there any reference link for 'onended' own event type in HTML5 video?

Comment: .addEventListener("ended",... is working...but for next video play its not firing.... if i but alert it will fire play correctly

Comment: My code and even your own works perfectly fine here. 
Be sure your script ist located after the `<video>` Element, that's the only reason I can think of why it doesn't work for you.