# how to display multiple videos one by one dynamically in loop using HTML5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

am trying to display multiple videos one by one using html5 and java script.. but its not coming.. i used the below code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>video example</title>
</head>
<script>
video_count =1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("ss");
video=document.getElementById("myVideo");

function run(){
        video_count++;
        //alert(video_count);
        if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
        var nextVideo = "video/video"+video_count+".mp4";
        //videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
        alert(nextVideo);
        videoPlayer.setAttribute("src", nextVideo[video_count]);
        videoPlayer.play();
   }
videoPlayer.onended(function(e) {
     if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
    } 
 run();
};
</script>
<body onload="run();">
<video id="myVideo" height="400" width="400" autoplay>   
  <source id="ss"  src="video/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

currently code is displaying only first video and it will stop...

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 video loop src change on end play function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521012/html5-video-loop-src-change-on-end-play-function-not-working)

Comment: why do you ask a question twice?

Comment: i tried both but its not working for me

Answer (score 11):

Let me show mine :D

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Subway Maps</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body onload="onload();">
    <video id="idle_video" width="1280" height="720" onended="onVideoEnded();"></video>
    <script>
        var video_list      = ["Skydiving Video - Hotel Room Reservation while in FreeFall - Hotels.com.mp4",
                                "Experience Conrad Hotels & Resorts.mp4",
                                "Mount Airy Casino Resort- Summer TV Ad 2.mp4"
                            ];
        var video_index     = 0;
        var video_player    = null;

        function onload(){
            console.log("body loaded");
            video_player        = document.getElementById("idle_video");
            video_player.setAttribute("src", video_list[video_index]);
            video_player.play();
        }

        function onVideoEnded(){
            console.log("video ended");
            if(video_index < video_list.length - 1){
                video_index++;
            }
            else{
                video_index = 0;
            }
            video_player.setAttribute("src", video_list[video_index]);
            video_player.play();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: For this to work you need to add `muted="muted"` for `<video>` tag

Comment: It refresh the video element when video ends, how to eliminate that blip and play next video smoothly?

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>video example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="myVideo" height="400" width="400" autoplay onended="run();">   
        <source id="ss"  src="video/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>

    <script>
        video_count =1;
        videoPlayer = document.getElementById("ss");        
        video=document.getElementById("myVideo");

        function run(){
            video_count++;
            if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
            videoPlayer.setAttribute("src","video/video"+video_count+".mp4");       
            video.load();
            video.play();
            
       }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Changes:

- Placed the javascript code just before closing the body tag to ensure that the video object is loaded before the script is run.
- video element already has an "onended" attribute so you can call the run function from there.

  `videoPlayer.setAttribute("src", nextVideo[video_count]);`  has an issue. `nextVideo[video_count]` implies that nextVideo is an array but is not . Its a string. So you can directly use nextVideo when setting the attribute.

  `videoPlayer = document.getElementById("ss");` gets the source element. You cannot call the play() function on that object, simply because that function isn't defined for it. So `video.play()` should work just fine.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: am gettin these two error  Denying load of chrome-  extension://kdidombaedgpfiiedeimiebkmbilgmlc/css/jquery_ui/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Comment: can any one tell me how to set time duration for each video in the above code?

Comment: as we are accessing videos one by one from the folder video_count, if any one of the video is deleted in the folder.. how to skip that video and go to next one? can anyone suggest me in this part?

Comment: For this to work i had to add video.load(); before video.play();.

Comment: @This_is_me only video.load(); is enough to load the next video and start playing it.

Comment: For this to work you also need to add `muted="muted"` for `<video>` tag

Comment: I'm getting this : script.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: videoPlayer.setAttribute is not a function

Answer (score 2):

before this function call video.play(); need add: video.load();
otherwise it will still display the previous video. So the code should be

**video.load();**

**video.play();**

Answer (score 0):

```
<video id="myVideo" height="400" width="400" autoplay onended="run();">
```

Add controls auto muted inside video tag.

```
<video id="myVideo" height="400" width="400" autoplay onended="run();" controls auto muted >
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It's working fine. Thanks for you!

Little bit modified code I have attached below, I hope this is helpful for who searching the video plays continuously with entire screen,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kLUK.png)

Comment: Please do not put images of code, instead paste the code directly in the editor and format it as code. Help on formatting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: This was not a reply, it was a comment, which should have been placed under any reply you want to thank.