# Web: How to play audio files one after the other without a delay ?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web, html5-audio

I have urls of several audio files like this:

`example.net/{num}.mp3`

And I would like to play them one after the other without a delay between them.

I tried having two audio elements with `preload=true` and switching between them, but I still have a delay.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm sure you already thought of this, but have you confirmed that there is no silence built into the audio tracks?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see the actual code of what you have so far, because I'm not 100% sure what "switching between them" means, but I wrote the following example which starts the next file playing before the first one finishes.  You specify a set amount of "overlap", and it starts playing the next file JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76xqhupw/4/

```
const OVERLAP_TIME = 1.0; //seconds

const song1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
const song2 = document.getElementById('audio2');

song1.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  if (song1.duration - song1.currentTime <= OVERLAP_TIME) {
    song2.play();
  }
});

song1.play();
```

This is just relevant to playing the next audio element instantly, since you said you already had two audio elements, but if I'm missing something let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) event, `Array.prototype.shift()` to set `src` of element to next item within array, if array `.length` is greater than `0`, call `.load()`, `.play()`

```
var url = "example.net/"
var type = ".mp3";
var n = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
var audio = document.querySelector("audio");
audio.onended = function() {
 if (n.length) {
  this.src =  url + n.shift() + type;
  this.load();
  this.play();
 }
}
audio.src = url + n[0] + type;
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
<head>
    <title>Subway Maps</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body onload="onload();">
    <video id="idle_video" width="1280" height="720" onended="onVideoEnded();"></video>
    <script>
        var video_list      = ["Skydiving Video - Hotel Room Reservation while in FreeFall - Hotels.com.mp4",
                                "Experience Conrad Hotels & Resorts.mp4",
                                "Mount Airy Casino Resort- Summer TV Ad 2.mp4"
                            ];
        var video_index     = 0;
        var video_player    = null;

        function onload(){
            console.log("body loaded");
            video_player        = document.getElementById("idle_video");
            video_player.setAttribute("src", video_list[video_index]);
            video_player.play();
        }

        function onVideoEnded(){
            console.log("video ended");
            if(video_index < video_list.length - 1){
                video_index++;
            }
            else{
                video_index = 0;
            }
            video_player.setAttribute("src", video_list[video_index]);
            video_player.play();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

for refrence [how to display multiple videos one by one dynamically in loop using HTML5 and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965355/how-to-display-multiple-videos-one-by-one-dynamically-in-loop-using-html5-and-ja)