# Playing two videos in queue

Tags: html, html5-video

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop>
  <source src="movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie2.mp4" type="video/mpr">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The code above will play `movie1.mp4` over and over again. What I want to achieve is to play those two videos one after the other. I mean after playing `movie1.mp4`, the `movie2.mp4` will play next.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archieve this by doing:

```
<video id="homevideo" width="100%" autoplay onended="run()">
    <source src="app/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
    <source src="app/video2.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>

video_count =1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");

function run(){
        video_count++;
        if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
        var nextVideo = "app/video"+video_count+".mp4";
        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
        videoPlayer.play();
   };
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521012/html5-video-loop-src-change-on-end-play-function-not-working)

Comment: I dont understand why you set the video_count to 4, since there is only 2 videos. if(video_count == 4) video_count = 1

Comment: Is there a way to get the size of the video list dynamically? such as videolist.size()???

Comment: You just need to get the max count for example if you going to use 3 videos set the max to 4 or you could do a count of the video by assigning a class and due a count for how many times this class is displayed.

Comment: hehehe... okay... sounds like static, but anyway, thanks!