# Automatically play and loop an array of videos, and change CSS with each

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Firstly, I *am* a code novice, and I appreciate that my ignorance may not be overly welcome. Nonetheless, if you are willing to indulge and help me, I would appreciate it a lot.

So, it appears that in previous years and in response to other people, people have expressed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521012/html5-video-loop-src-change-on-end-play-function-not-working as an answer to the first part of my question. Code from aforementioned answer:

```
<video id="homevideo" width="100%" autoplay onended="run()">
    <source src="app/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

&

```
video_count =1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");

function run(){
        video_count++;
        if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
        var nextVideo = "app/video"+video_count+".mp4";
        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
        videoPlayer.play();
   };
```

To expand on this, however, how would one construct this if the videos aren't following a video[number].mp4 naming convention? I should say, I found and tried the solution offered [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/853157/How-to-play-array-of-Videos-in-HTML) initially, but it would only loop the first video and not play the others for some reason.

Lastly, and additionally, I'd like each video to have a pre-defined CSS change attached to it. For instance, when a specific video plays, the background-color of the parent element would change to an assigned colour. The same would happen for each of the videos in the array, each having a colour pre-defined that the background colour would change to.

If people are able to offer a solution, and also briefly explain it so that I may hopefully learn, that would be terrific!

Many thanks in advance, people.

Comment: You could use DOM traversal to find the next video in the page, if you don't want to explicitly number them. It would help to see a more complete sample of your HTML. You can make the CSS change on the playing video by listening for the [events]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events] raised on the `video` element, such as `playing` and `pause` or `ended`

Answer (score 0):

Just make an array with classes matching your videos:

```
var example = ['foo', 'bar', 'faz', 'video4'];
```

And then you set it in your loop, after `var nextVideo` (you already have that counter, just reuse it);

```
var videoPlayer.classList = example[video_count-1]; // -1 as you count from 1->4, but the array 0->3
```